# DKIM key in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, deliverability, dkim

How do I generate DKIM key in Marketing Cloud? MC is already being used for sending email, so is there a mechanism to generate DKIM key in MC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not your responsibility to generate a DKIM key for Marketing Cloud. You have two options on how to ensure that the domain you are sending from has a valid DKIM key:

- **Delegated domain:** If you are [delegating](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_subdomain_delegation_guide.htm&type=5) the domain to the name servers of Salesforce (like most customers do), then Saleforce will manage the DNS entries for you. This also goes for the DKIM key, which in practice is stored in a TXT record. Hence you should not worry on the managing the actual DKIM key yourself.
- **Self hosting:** If you are self hosting your DNS records for the domain in question, Salesforce provides you with a zone file holding all the relevant DNS records, including the DKIM as a TXT record. Please see an example of such a file here below:

```
$TTL 1H
$ORIGIN mc.example.com.


@               IN MX 10        reply.s50.exacttarget.com.
@               IN A            192.168.0.1

bounce          IN MX 10        bounce.s50.exacttarget.com.
reply           IN MX 10        reply.s50.exacttarget.com.
leave           IN MX 10        reply.s50.exacttarget.com.

image           IN CNAME        images.s50.exacttarget.com.edgesuite.net.
view            IN CNAME        view.virt.s50.exacttarget.com.
click           IN CNAME        click.virt.s50.exacttarget.com.
pages           IN CNAME        pages.virt.s50.exacttarget.com.
cloud           IN CNAME        pub.s50.exacttarget.com.

mta             IN A            192.168.0.1


50dkim1._domainkey  IN TXT ( "v=DKIM1; k=rsa; p=MIIBIjANBgkqhkxUf1MK/hRdAAOCAQ8AKCAQExUf1MK/hRdSE2FxqncAgzL"
"3gtcL1clvZa70025dbH66oD4/B7/MEYkuwEUE9vhhU5sJ6oNVby//Nu7U3uC"
"lgSVrzibGUprxUf1MK/hRdFqc6mwlxUf1MK/hRdRtNGFcLWd0PXRg/gyE53R"
"YYjacIfNVOd9DB5iRXs4BVFqc6mh47sjNpwmJ0yDKmqUpW0ZJL8OuLPHEwbt"
"qEktTMCwt7zp4X+/mR5kpAyFo/mjVlOTBT4LD3xUf1MK/hRdYa6FB0xXH1Vd"
"..."
"..." )


##the above TXT record should be a single multi-line TXT record


@               IN TXT          "v=spf1 include:cust-spf.exacttarget.com -all"
bounce          IN TXT          "v=spf1 include:cust-spf.exacttarget.com -all"
reply           IN TXT          "v=spf1 include:cust-spf.exacttarget.com -all"
```

There is an good [blog post here](https://digitalmarketingoncloud.com/deliverability/marketing-cloud-dkim-faq/), on the topic of DKIM in Marketing Cloud

Comment: Thanks for the asnwer @Lukas Lunow. Could you advice how to request the zone file with  DNS records etc.?

Comment: @Pinja This is usually provided once you request configuration of a Private Domain or a Sender Authentication Package. You can raise a support ticket with Salesforce to request the zone file for existing domain.